# Why isn't may nav moving back into position after toggle?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've created a toggle menu.

However, when I close the menu the toggle link remains in the position it was when the menu was open.

Working example on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/rnichael/pen/MYyBGQ)

What I want is for the nav items to return to their original position.

**HTML**

```
<body class="menu">
<header>
    <a href="#" class="menu-toggle">toggle</a>
    <nav class="main-nav">
        <ul>
            <li>Link</li>
            <li>Link</li>
            <li>Link</li>
            <li>Link</li>
            <li>Link</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <nav class="menu-side mobile">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    color: #000;
}


.main-nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 28px;
    float: right;
}

.menu-toggle {
    float: right;
}

.menu-side {
    background-color: #333;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    color: white;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: -231px;
    width: 210px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;  
}

.menu {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
}

.menu-open {
    right: 231px;
}

.menu-open .menu-side {
    right: 0;
}

.menu-side,
.menu {
    -webkit-transition: right 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: right 0.2s ease;
    transition: right 0.2s ease;
}


@media (min-width: 700px)  {
    .menu-side, .menu-toggle {
        display: none;
    }
}

    @media (max-width: 700px)  {

    .main-nav {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

**JS**

```
 (function() {
    var body = $('body');
    $('.menu-toggle').bind('click', function(){
        body.toggleClass('menu-open');
            return false;

    });

 $('.menu-side li').on('click', function (){
 $(".menu-side").animate({ "right": "-=231px" }, "2000" );
  });
 })();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See a working example here:
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/kxq42het/1/)

Add the `body.toggleClass` function to the `.menu-side li` click function as well like so :

```
         (function() {
            var body = $('body');
            $('.menu-toggle').bind('click', function(){
                body.toggleClass('menu-open');
                    return false;

            });

         $('.menu-side li').on('click', function (){
         body.toggleClass('menu-open');
         return false;
         $(".menu-side").animate({ "right": "-231px" }, "2000" );
    });

})();
```

The reason why it wasn't working is simple, on the `.menu-side li`you were only animating `"right": "-231px"`.

**Update**

Were you wrong to write -231px? Well, no, since that's the width of the container...but you can always use : `$(".menu-side").animate({ "right": "-100%" }, "2000" );` if you are thinking of changing that width anytime soon. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/kxq42het/2/)

Comment: coolers, seems to work. I'm just curious; was I wrong setting it to -231, given that's the width of the menu?

Comment: Well, best of luck :)

Comment: When I expand the browser, the links outside of the toggle menu don't return to their starting position

Comment: Uhm, there must be something else wrong in the rest of your code cause i'm testing now in the jsfiddle and everything is fine...

Comment: @michael I've triple checked, everything is ok with the code I provided, Something else from the rest of your code must be interfering with it.

Comment: Entire code is on the codepen. Start with the browser small. Then toggle open nav, then expand browser. You'll see that when the MQ kicks in the links are shifted towards the left.

Comment: Then you are not expanding the browser enough...whenever I\m expanding the preview container the toggle button hides and the links appear...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66861/discussion-between-alin-and-michael).

Comment: The links appear, but the should be set way to the right. I think I need to force close the menu on browser expansion.

Comment: I see no such thing...sorry, what browser are you testing on ? Does removing the -100% and adding back the -231px help fix your problem? Even if i start in small browser state and toggle the menu and resize, the links show sticked to the right side of the page